# Mac selects files instead of dragging them

Tags: finder

When you click on unselected file and start moving it up to start dragging, mac os selects sibling files instead of dragging.

Comment: Any comments guys?)

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail what you are trying to accomplish and where it fails to work as you expect it to? You might also want to look at the Help Center for some ideas on what helps to make a question understandable to a wider audience.

Comment: Ok, thanks, probably I should add a gif to illustrate what I'm saying. Will do it when I get to that mac.

Comment: I don't know why I stumbled upon this only now, it always worked that way. I figured out my confusion, see the answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you start dragging in white space near to files, mac os will select the files. If you start dragging with cursor above the files it actually drags them.

[image]